# How to show that $\#(\mathbb Z^n/N) = \det(A)$ where $N$ is the subgroup of $\mathbb Z^n$ generated by columns of a square matrix $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

$A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with integer coefficients. I am trying to understand a) and b) claims.
a) $Z^n/N$ is finite $\Leftrightarrow$ $det(A)\neq 0$
b) #$(Z^n/N)=|det(A)|$

Looking at the linked answer, I can reduce $A$ to normal form by multiplying by unimodular matrices and this multiplication does not change $|det(A)|$. I understand that the $det(A)=d_1d_2..d_r$ where $d_i|d_{i+1}$ and $d_1,..d_r$ are entries of normal form. But I don't understand why $Z^n/AZ^n \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} Z/d_iZ$? The explanations I have seen in MSE are in the context of rings and I don't know them yet. Any hint to explain the isomorphism using group theory language is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is posted many times on MSE. Use search!

Comment: I have tried that and could not find anything unfortunately.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881454/corollary-to-smith-normal-form

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416648/how-to-show-that-the-kernel-of-a-map-f-mathbbzm-to-g-is-free-of-rank-m-w

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648447/card-mathbbzn-m-mathbbzn-textrmdetm/2648596#2648596

Comment: Thanks for those links.